Why does my OpenMP app sometimes use only 1 thread, sometimes 3, sometimes all cores?
I noticed that my OpenMP-enabled app sometimes only uses 1 thread.

If I wait a couple minutes, it uses more threads (e.g. 3).
If I wait 15 minutes, it uses all threads.

Why?

Quick answer
You may be using OpenCV which turns on OMP_DYNAMIC, and the GCC libomp implementation of that depends on the 15-minute load average (a bad idea in my opinion).
Full answer
This the default implementation of libgomp OMP_DYNAMIC / omp_set_dynamic() is e.g. on Linux libgomp/config/linux/proc.c
/* When OMP_DYNAMIC is set, at thread launch determine the number of
   threads we should spawn for this team.  */
/* ??? I have no idea what best practice for this is.  Surely some
   function of the number of processors that are *still* online and
   the load average.  Here I use the number of processors online
   minus the 15 minute load average.  */

unsigned
gomp_dynamic_max_threads (void) {
// ...
    return n_onln - loadavg;

OMP_DYNAMIC is really bad

Because of this logic, your app will use only 1 thread, even though the system is completely idle now, just because it was busy 10 minutes ago.
The dynamic limit is determined at process start (loading time), and fixed forever.

So started programs stay slow forever if they were started at a time 5 minutes after the system was busy.


It means a server can never achieve full utilisation when working down a queue of jobs.

Say you have 8 cores, and a queue of N jobs to process, each of which takes 15 minutes full-CPU.
The first jobs starts at 0 15-min-utilisation, thus using all cores.
The next job starts, using only 1 core.
The next job starts, using only 7 cores.
The next job starts, using only 1 cores.
The next job starts, using only 7 cores.
...
In the long run, the server uses only half of its cores on average.


It makes performance behaviour completely irreproducible.

None of this behaviour is documented in libgomp or the OpenMP spec for OMP_DYNAMIC.
Those docs sound like the behaviour is nice "runtime-dynamic" when in fact it is fixed across the process's liftime, and based on ultra-slow rolling averages.
In my opinion, somebody should file a GCC bug for this.

Edit: I did it: The implementation of OMP_DYNAMIC is not dynamic - https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=115367

OpenCV
Unfortunately the popular OpenCV library turned this on by default in 2018.
This is called at program loading time, as revealed by gdb:
(gdb) break omp_set_dynamic

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff706c330 in omp_set_dynamic () from /nix/store/7c0yrczwxn58f9gk9ipawdh607vh067k-gcc-12.2.0-lib/lib/libgomp.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff706c330 in omp_set_dynamic () from /nix/store/7c0yrczwxn58f9gk9ipawdh607vh067k-gcc-12.2.0-lib/lib/libgomp.so.1
#1  0x00007ffff6c7ed21 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_parallel.cpp () from /nix/store/z2sc2pxysa8shfs9laj0xsmj87qhaq5h-opencv-4.7.0/lib/libopencv_core.so.407
#2  0x00007ffff7fcefae in call_init () from /nix/store/46m4xx889wlhsdj72j38fnlyyvvvvbyb-glibc-2.37-8/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  0x00007ffff7fcf09c in _dl_init () from /nix/store/46m4xx889wlhsdj72j38fnlyyvvvvbyb-glibc-2.37-8/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007ffff7fe4a80 in _dl_start_user () from /nix/store/46m4xx889wlhsdj72j38fnlyyvvvvbyb-glibc-2.37-8/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

So if your app dynamically links against OpenCV, this happens.
I filed a bug to disable it: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/25717
Workaround for OpenCV
Set the environment variable
OPENCV_FOR_OPENMP_DYNAMIC_DISABLE=1  yourprogram...


Curious how it is done in LLVM. They used to use libgomp, but now supposed to have independent implementation

I'd be delighted if somebody could link the LLVM implementation!
